# Two buffers are being sent via XMLHttp

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have tried asking this before but I will try to be more descriptive this time. I have a Chrome extension popup. When a user wants to log a message from my extnesion to my backend they press "submit". In my background task I have used `onMessage.addListener`. When that background listener gets a `request.task == "log_results_survey"` (which means that the user hit submit in the popup task) this runs:

```
    if (request.task =="log_results_survey"){
          send_to_logger_survey(request, sender, sendResponse);
          console.log("sent to logger_survey\n");
          };
```

Send_to_logger_survey (also in background task) appears below:

```
    function send_to_logger_survey(request, sender, sendResponse)
    {
    var myArray=[];
    var jsonResponse2;
    var d=new Date(); 

    myArray.push(email);
    myArray.push(request.values);  //contains chosen values
    myArray.push(Math.random());   //push random number
    console.log("sent to server\n");
    var json = JSON.stringify(myArray);
    var n = json.length;   //this must be less than 1472 to avoid fragmentation
    var url=szHost;  
    url=url.concat('/Subit_backend/logger_survey');
    var xhr2 = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr2.onerror = function() { alert('error'); };
    xhr2.open('POST', url, true);

    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json")
    xhr2.setRequestHeader("X-Requested-With",'xmlhttprequest');
    xhr2.setRequestHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");

    xhr2.onload = function (){

            if((xhr2.status === 200)&&(xhr2.readyState===4)) {
                if (xhr2.responseText==="")
                    var jsonResponse2="empty";
                else
                    var jsonResponse2 = JSON.parse(xhr2.responseText);
                sendResponse({task: jsonResponse2});
              return true; //The sendResponse callback is only valid if used synchronously, or if the event handler returns true to indicate that it will respond asynchronously.   
            }
    };
    xhr2.send(json);
    }
```

What I am seeing (on the server and also with wireshark) is that this is sending two copies of the same buffer from two contiguous ports on the client (49814 and 49815)! You can see the two in buffers 41 and 42. Any idea how I can get this back to just one copy of the buffer?

Strange detail: when I look at the two random numbers that have been recvd by the host, they are different in the two different buffers. It seems that `send_to_logger_survey()` is running twice, but with the debugger I only see it stop at the breakpoint once. 
[image: wireshark capture]

Comment: Sounds like either a bug in Chrome (you can report it on https://crbug.com) or a consequence of having background.js included in html of another open page in your extension like maybe a popup in another window or an options page.

Comment: Thx. I reported it. What is strange is that Devtools only reports a single buffer although Wireshark shows two. More strange is that the random number that was put into the buffer is different when looked at in the buffer that arrives at the server.

Comment: In the meantime, I managed to create a workaround in the code. The crux of it is   if(is_null($_SESSION[$email_keye])){
                $this->session->set_tempdata($email_keye, 'value', 1);  //block for 1 sec
            }. I am blocking the same user from sending in another buffer for 1 second. Not the greatest but it works for now.